# Fetching information from a database

Tags: c#, sql, database

This is going to be a bit of a noob question but I have a problem that when I want to fetch data according to a foreign key in another table, and the problem is I cannot figure out the sql to do it.

I have the following tables:

- **USERS**: `login, password, role_id, userDetail_id`
- **ROLES**: `role_id, role_name`
- **USER_DETAILS**: `userDetail_id, name surname`

Now I want to get the name and surname of all the users where the role_id is 4 and display them in an asp drop-down control.

Thanks for any help because it really baffled me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sql will be :

```
 DataTable dt =   @"Select name, surname from USER_DETAILS as ud
    Inner Join USERS as u on ud.userDetail_id = u.userDetail_id
    Inner join ROLES as r on u.role_id = r.role_id
    where u.role_id = 4";
```

Then you can bind your datatable to dropdown :

```
    dropdown.DataSource = dt;
    dropdown.DataTextField = "name";
    dropdown.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, surname
FROM USER_DETAILS ud, USERS u
WHERE ud.userDetail_id = u.userDetail_id
 AND u.role_id = 4;
```

Comment: You could also do it with `LEFT JOIN`
`SELECT name, surname FROM USER_DETAILS ud LEFT JOIN USERS u ON (ud.userDetail_id = u.userDetail_id) WHERE u.role_id=4;`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ud.name, ud.surname 
FROM user_details ud, roles uroles, users u
WHERE ud.userDetail_id = u.userDetail_id 
AND u.role_id = uroles.role_id 
AND uroles.role_id = 4
```